# Looking for Examples and Source of a working Dojo TreeGrid widget

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

Anyone know of some working examples with source of the dojox.grid.TreeGrid widget? The docs on DojoCampus don't have an example and the nightly test doesn't have source.

Supposedly, this is trunked in Dojo 1.4, but I can't get it working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at the **test_tree*.html** files at [`dojo` **grid** tests](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/) ?

Comment: This looks good. I couldn't find it before because the tree tests aren't in there own directory. I wasn't expecting them to be with the regular grid tests.